# Can Metro apps be created for internal / limited distribution?

Tags: digital-signature, microsoft-metro, windows-store

Is there (or will there be) a distribution channel with Windows 8 that allows Metro apps to be built for internal company use only, or for a select group of partners?  Or is the app-store the only possible route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Primer for current Windows Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464912) on Microsoft's site indicates that for Metro apps,

> Side-loading is available for enterprises and developers.

So, yes, you can side load applications, but it's currently limited to individual developers and enterprise customers.

The [TechNet article on Managing the Windows Store](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh832040.aspx) provides more details:

> Sideloading, which is available in both Windows 8 Consumer Preview and
>   Windows Server “8” Beta, refers to installing apps directly to a
>   device without going through the Windows Store. LOB apps do not need
>   to be certified by Microsoft and cannot be installed through the
>   Windows Store but they must be signed with a certificate chained to a
>   trusted root certificate. It is recommended that IT administrators use
>   the same technical certification that is done by the Windows Store on
>   LOB apps.

The [TechNet Article on How to Add and Remove Apps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx) provides the specifics on how to sign and side load applications on Windows 8 and Windows Server 8.

Comment: Thanks - it was the term "side-loading" that I needed apparently.  See this page for the actual steps: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx